# How to solve security vulnerabilities in my github repository dependencies?

Tags: github, dependency-management

When i'm commit i am facing this problem that says:

```
GitHub found 2 vulnerabilities on my github repository default branch (1 high, 1 moderate). To find out more, visit:
 mygithub reposity/security/dependabot
```

I tried to solve this but failed.

[potential security vulnerabilities in dependencies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGcp9.png)

Comment: You should add information about what the errors are and what you did to attempt to resolve them.   At the minute, this question is kind of like saying "I tried to cook something my kitchen and the recipe didn't work out, help me." People will need much more specific information to help you in any way.  Maybe say the vulnerability you tried to fix, what you tried to do to mitigate it, give a link to your repo so people can check out what it says, etc.

Comment: Did you open the URL mentioned in the error message? It should show you a list of vulnerabilities and when available will offer the ability to automatically fix the issue through an automatically generated pull request. You can also try to run `npm audit fix` locally to see if npm can solve the issue. Or use snyk `npx snyk test --all-projects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate to the repository's Security tab you should have an overview of the vulnerabilities found in your repo. If Dependabot knows how to fix these issues, it will offer the ability to generate a pull request to fix the issue automatically:

[image: Generate pull request]

Once generated, you can verify whether the proposed changes don't break anything, then merge the code:

[image: Merge auto-generated pull request]

You can also try to manually resolve these issues locally using:

```
npm audit fix
```

or

```
npm install snyk -g
snyk auth
snyk test
snyk wizard
```

And then push the changes.

Or manually update the dependencies with vulnerabilities:

```
// use @latest or a more specific non-vulnerable version
npm install package@latest --save
```